# Type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration

I am getting this error after i published my site into remote server.

> Type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from
>   'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.

It works fine on the local server. I havent moved any views or viewstart pages

It used to work fine in the remote server as well, but after the i made some updates and pushed the new code to the server i am getting this error.

I have made changes to the code but nothing to web.config or any viewstart page.

I also have `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />` in my web.config.

I had created new controller,views  using the entity framework, but no changes to viewstart files. Is the anything else that i need to look into?

Update: I had installed nuget package

> MvcCheckBoxList 1.4.4.5

But i have unistalled it .. still getting the error

Comment: have you checked you **_ViewStart.cshtml** file on server?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem all the time, in my case is not what you see, is what you can´t see... :P

Enable "View all Files" in the web project that is failing, and search for a file that seems correct but is not included in visual studio, **and delete it**.
If it fails in your deployment folder, try to clean the folder as well, and re-deploy the site, you might have unnecesary files that might cause the same problem.

In my case, at the root of the webproject I had an extra copy of _ViewStart.cshtml (excluded from the project), I deleted that file, and that did the trick.

Hope it helps, let me know if this solve your problem as well.

Answer (score -3):

make sure  the file "_viewstart.cshtml" is exists on "areas/yourarea/views" folder